# Unit Testing for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test a class that I have written in Python called NeuralNetworkModel(). It is a class that takes in a file and trains a ANN model and saves it as a pickle file. Currently I have a very basic unit test that the class is reading in a file as a data frame correctly. My code is below.

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
from NN_model import NeuralNetworkModel

class NeuralNetworkModel(unittest.TestCase):

    def test(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    @classmethod
    def set_up(cls):
        """ SetUp """
        test_input_dir = '/home/student/data_analytics/prediction_model/clean_files/'
        test_file_name = '25_1.csv'
        try:
            data = pd.read_csv(test_input_dir + test_file_name, sep = ',')
        except IOError:
            print('Cannot Open File')
        cls.fixture = data

    def test_dataFrame_constrcuted_as_expected(self):
        """ Test that the dataframe read in equals what you expect"""
        foo = pd.DataFrame()
        assert_frame_equal(self.fixture, foo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Error I get when I run this file is

```
ERROR: test_dataFrame_constrcuted_as_expected (__main__.NeuralNetworkModel)
Test that the dataframe read in equals what you expect
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_NN_model.py", line 25, in test_dataFrame_constrcuted_as_expected
    assert_frame_equal(self.fixture, foo)
AttributeError: 'NeuralNetworkModel' object has no attribute 'fixture'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I am very new to unit testing and I struggle with it, but I can't work out why my test isn't passing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're naming things correctly. `unittest` doesn't recognize `set_up()`, so it never gets called. Rename it to `setUpClass()` and it should work.

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass) for reference.